# .htaccess rewrite rule not working on remote site

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, url-rewriting

Here is the code inside my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^items/(\d+)/?$     items.php?item_id=$1
```

My directory structure:

```
|_root_folder_name
|-->category
   |_ .htaccess
   |_ index.php
   |_ items.php
```

The url: `localhost/root_folder_name/category/items/2/`. It works correctly on the local machine and I get the value of **`echo $_GET['item_id']`** as **`2`**. But when I visit the remote site with the url: `xyz.com/category/items/2/`

the **`item_id`** variable is not detected at all. I tried `print_r($_GET)` and it printed an empty array.

Could you please point out what's wrong with my rewrite rule. I hope I was was able to explain the issue properly.

Comment: can you give some more information on the environments of your local and remote server, like apache version, the OS, have you added `AllowOverride all` onto the `Directory` directive on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It

After lot of attempts I just changed the file name from `items.php` to `item.php` and its working correctly now. I guess there was a clash between the RewriteRule and the file name as they were similar.